# Issue while formatting number using thymleaf

Tags: html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm facing an issue with number formatting in Thymeleaf.
I have an html template which is showing data for bills by looping over each bill.
Most of the fields are String type but brokerageRate field is of type Double in my data model.
When I run my code, it gives me the following exception
Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#numbers.formatDecimal(bill.brokerageRate,3,2)"

`<thymeleaf.version>3.0.11.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>`

I have tried out different options provided in the documentation of Thymeleaf, but I get the same exception. 
https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html

Following is my template:-

```
<tbody>
                         <tr th:each="bill : ${bills}">
                                <td><a th:text="${bill.invoiceNum}" th:href="@{'/show/' + ${bill.id}}"></a></td>
                                <td th:text="${bill.invoiceDate}"></td>
                                <td th:text="${bill.receiverName}"></td>
                                <td th:text="${bill.receiverAddress}"></td>
                                <td th:text="${bill.receiverState}"></td>
                                <td th:text="${bill.receiverGstNum}"></td>
                                <td th:text="${bill.propertyAddress}"></td>
                                <td th:text="${#numbers.formatDecimal(bill.brokerageRate,3,2)}"></td>
                                <td th:text="${bill.brokerageAmount}"></td>
                                <td th:text="${bill.cgstPct}"></td>
                                <td th:text="${bill.cgstAmount}"></td>
                                <td th:text="${bill.sgstPct}"></td>
                                <td th:text="${bill.sgstAmount}"></td>
                                <td th:text="${bill.igstPct}"></td>
                                <td th:text="${bill.igstAmount}"></td>
                                <td th:text="${bill.totalGstAmount}"></td>
                                <td th:text="${bill.brokerageDueAfterTax}"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
```

Request you to please help me understand where am I wrong.

Comment: What's the whole stacktrace -- it should tell you what the problem is?  If I had to guess, I would guess that sometimes `bill.brokerageRate` is null since the expression looks alright to me.

Comment: note of caution - you may want to use BigDecimal instead of Double for values that require precision

Comment: The problem got resolved. I used ${bill.brokerageRate} instead of using the numbers.format decimal syntax and it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
th:text="${#numbers.formatDecimal({bill.brokerageRate},3,2)}"
```